# Copying Data from Oracle to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, oracle11g, enterprisedb

We have a daily process that pulls all data out of a number of tables in an Oracle database and imports them into a Postgress (EnterpriseDB) database - Version 8.4.

We are currently using a java application to select * from each table, change the keywords (date, timestamp, etc) and then import them into the Postgres Database.

Are there any tools available in Postgres that would provide a more efficient manner of doing this?  I should note that there are CLOBs that are being transported over.

Answer (score 5):

There is [Ora2Pg](http://ora2pg.darold.net/), which is intended as a one-time-migration tool, but it might work in your case as well.  I think of it as an Oracle-to-PostgreSQL pg_dump.

Comment: Thanks.  I will have to check this out and see if it takes care of our needs.